# Delphi use generic class to manage components

Tags: delphi, generics

I have made a program to make some tests with generics. It looks like this:

[image]

Basically you can use the 2 buttons below to add a button or a edit and they will display the current date. Instead of making 2 different classes for buttons and edits, I thought that I could have made a generic class like this:

```
type
 TGeneric<T: class, constructor> = class(TObject)
  private
   item: T;
   date: TDateTime;
   function getTime: string;
  public
   constructor Create;
   destructor Destroy; override;
   procedure showLife(Sender: TObject);
   property time: string read getTime;
   property myObj: T read item write item;
 end;

implementation

{ TGeneric<T> }

constructor TGeneric<T>.Create;
begin
 inherited;
 date := Now;
end;

destructor TGeneric<T>.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TGeneric<T>.getTime: string;
begin
  Result := FormatDateTime('c', date);
end;
```

The class above is in a unit called UnitGeneric. I have another unit called Unit1 that contains this implementation:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a: TGeneric<TButton>;
begin

 a := TGeneric<TButton>.Create;
 try

  a.myObj := TButton.Create(Self);
  a.myObj.Parent := Self;
  a.myObj.SetBounds(aLeft, aTop, 200, 35);
  a.myObj.Caption := a.time;
  setTop(40);    
 finally
  a.Free;
 end;

end;

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var a: TGeneric<TEdit>;
begin

 a := TGeneric<TEdit>.Create;
 try
  a.myObj := TEdit.Create(Self);
  a.myObj.Parent := Self;
  a.myObj.SetBounds(aLeft, aTop, 200, 35);
  a.myObj.Text := a.time;
  setTop(40);
 finally
  a.Free;
 end;

end;
```

I'd have two main questions for this:

1. Am I creating the components (TEdits and TButtons) in a correct way? As you can see I have declared in the generic class a `item: T` variable that can be accessed using the property. Then I manage the creation of the object and so on directly in the form. Would it be better to do it somewhere else (maybe in the constructor of the generic class)?
2. I know that when I set the owner for a component, the "father" will destroy all the childs. According with this reason, is it safe anyway if I create an object (TEdit or TButton) as above withotu a try-finally?

Note: In `1` I am asking in particular if that is the correct way to manage an object in a Generic class

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but one way you can test this is enable System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown. It's an amazing feature of Delphi!

Comment: It would be easier to get your generic class to create the controls. You already know the answer to the second question.